# Android studio request permission and IMEI/MEID

Tags: android

I have problem in permission request , when I run my application I get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUzXM.png). When i click on the "give me permission" it opens toast and ask me to allow or deny , when i click allow it will close the application. Then i should open it again and it will work correctly. When i click on the button there is toast message that I allow permission , Is there any fault in my code ?
Thank you

IN MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

in java code in onclick() function that name is onSubmit():

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private int PHONE_STATE_CODE=1;

  private Button button;
  TextView textView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView2 );
  }

  public void onSubmit(View v){
    TelephonyManager t = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService( 
    Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you have already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
      reqPhonePermission();
    }

    String me =t.getDeviceId();

    String id = t.getLine1Number();
  }
```

~~~~~~~
outside onClick()

```
private void reqPhonePermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("permission needed").setMessage("this permission needed")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},PHONE_STATE_CODE);

                    }
                }) .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},PHONE_STATE_CODE);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults ){
    if(requestCode == PHONE_STATE_CODE){
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is an image please select blue paragraph to see the photo on photo message that application stopped

Answer (score 1):

The method that requires permission should be called only if the permission is granted.
You can be sure that the permission is granted when one of these conditions are true:

- `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`
- `grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`

Try with this code:

```
public void onSubmit(View v){
    TelephonyManager t = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you have already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        methodThatRequiresPermission();
    } else {
        reqPhonePermission();
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults ){
    if(requestCode == PHONE_STATE_CODE){
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            methodThatRequiresPermission();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void methodThatRequiresPermission() { 
    String me =t.getDeviceId();
    String id = t.getLine1Number();

    //Use the values here
}
```